# What T-SQL statement can add leading zeros to a column of numbers?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to write a T-SQL statement that will examine a column of data and based on each record, make changes to the record.

The column is nvarchar and contains records that represent numbers from 1 to 1000.

For each number less than 1000, I want to add the correct number of leading zeros to produce a 4 digit number.

Exmaple: if the Number is 10, I would like to convert it to: 0010.
If the number is 781, I would like to convert it to 0781.

How can I accomplish this using SET statements (without a cursor)?

Comment: The bigger question is why are you storing numbers in a varchar column?

Comment: I'm maintaining a legacy program :)